# How can define listview widget in column widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to use listview in column, but i got a renderingbox error.
How can I solved that?

```
 class Test extends StatefulWidget {
      const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<Test> createState() => _TestState();
    }
    
    class _TestState extends State<Test> {
      bool active = false;
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Column(
          children: [
            ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Text("data");
            })
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Wrap your `ListView.builder` in `Expanded/Flexible` or use a `SizedBox` and give it a fixed height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `shrinkWrap: true,` inside `ListView.builder`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
Column(
  children: [
    ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: 5,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Text("data");
      },
    )
  ],
),
```

Result-> [image]